# What is best Spring Rest service as bridge or direct Kafta integration with it's Rest interface?

Tags: spring, rest, apache-kafka

I have a project requirement wherein I have a source system which will generates the events and I need to integrate it to the Kafka. Now i want to explore it in following ways:
 1. Is it best to have a java rest service to act as a bridge between my source and Kafka? What all best frameworks are available to achieve such integration.
 2. Is it best to integrate my source directly with Kafka using it's Kafka Rest interface?

Comment: What's wrong with Spring-Kafka?

Comment: @cricket_007, What is Spring-Kafka offering that vanilla Kafka client doesn't offer? I am just curious. TBH, In my experience, I haven't found many

Comment: It provides native Spring injection with annotations, healthchecks, and JSON serializers

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Directly write to kafka (using kafka's native protocol rather than using http) Reason is HTTP is an additional overhead and another point of failure which you can totally avoid. If it doesnt have to be performant you will be able to get away with HTTP wrapper, but it's not advisable .

FWIW, This is a hammer-nail programming pattern. When you have a hammer (HTTP protocol) in hand, everywhere you look you only see nails :)

Comment: Ok, i will explore the direction which you have provided.